# Youtube Next Previous Pagination with Json

Tags: api, youtube, pagination

I am getting nextPageToken from json result but still didn't work. Not no where problem exist, can anyone plz look into this and rectify and help me in this issue.

`
    $jsonURL = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&contentDetail&channelId= {$channelID}&type=video&maxResults=2&key={myAPiKey}");
    $result = json_decode($jsonURL, true);
    foreach ($result['items'] as $searchResult) {

```
$nPt = $result['nextPageToken']; 

$Tmburl = $searchResult['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
$views = $searchResult['statistics']['viewCount'];
$date = $searchResult['snippet']['publishedAt'];

echo '<h3>'.$searchResult['snippet']['title'].'</h3>';
echo '<img src="'.$Tmburl.'"/>';
echo '<p>'.$searchResult['snippet']['description'].'</p>';
}

// Pagination

echo '<h1><a href="?id='.$channelID.'&pageToken='.$result['nextPageToken'].'">next</a></h1>';
```

`

The Next - Previous Pagination not working. Even i m getting nextPageToken number but link not functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got, Just send pageToken value in Json URL, and pagination work.